# Trigger to change empty values to NULL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger where if an incoming value is empty (in other words ''), then insert NULL in the table. I have :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER avoid_empty 
BEFORE INSERT ON EVALUATION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF mark = '' THEN SET NEW.mark = NULL;
    END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Which executes without errors, but it doesn't do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `avoid_empty` BEFORE INSERT ON `EVALUATION`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.`mark` = '' THEN
        SET NEW.`mark` := NULL;
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vSWhqgWf4tX6aUK2tHS68t/0).

Comment: I have solved the problem by writing a special SQL query. I will mark your answer as solved anyway